# Bootstrap 4 how to lay out narrow text centred and vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm trying to layout some text - a heading and a paragraph, but when I constrain the width to 50% say with the `w-50` class.  The text jumps up to be arranged horizontally with the title.  Trying to change the flex direction and the align-center leaves the text and the title to the left hand side.

Below the text has width of 75%, how do I keep the same arrangment but set the width to 50%?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvXyzW

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center ">
            <h3 class="pt-5 pb-3">How can ExampleSite help you?</h3>
            <p class="feature-summary w-75">
                With us, not only can you find a great deal, but should your prices go up or something
                better
                come
                on
                the market we can find it automatically.
            </p>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you asking literally why you cannot have the text remain exactly as it is formatted in your `<p>` tag when the width changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row is flex-direction:row, so just change to flex-direction:column using the `flex-column` class. Use `align-items-center` to center horizontally.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-center flex-column align-items-center">
           <h3 class="pt-5 pb-3">How can ExampleSite help you?</h3>
           <p class="feature-summary w-50">
                    ..
          </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks I removed the justify-content-center as that was uneeded (was from the previous attempt to arrange the layout) but this works perfectly.  Is it normal to still use the row class when the direction has been changed to columns?